# Singular Perturbation in Hagan's 2002 SABR paper "Managing Smile Risk"

Tags: sabr, pde

I'm reading Hagan's 2002 paper Managing Smile Risk originally published on the WILMOTT magazine, and got something confusing.

**The set up**: $P(τ,f,α,K)$ is the solution of the problem as in Equation (A.13a)
$$P_τ=\frac12 ε^2 α^2 C^2 (f) P_{ff}+ε^2 ρνα^2 C(f) P_{fα}+ \frac12 ε^2 ν^2 α^2 P_{αα}$$
for $τ>0$, and boundary condition as in Equation (A.13b)
$$P=α^2 δ(f-K)$$
for $τ=0$.

Here $\varepsilon \ll 1$ is the perturbation; while $\rho$, $\nu$ are constants.

**Then it says**:

Using a straightforward perturbation expansion would yield a Gaussian
density to leading order, as in Equation (A.15a)
$$P=\frac{α}{\sqrt{2πε^2 C^2 (K)τ}}  \exp⁡\left[-\frac{(f-K)^2}{2ε^2 α^2 C^2 (K)τ}\right]⋅(1+⋯)$$

Since the “+⋯” involves powers of $(f-K)/εαC(K)$, this expansion would
become inaccurate as soon as $(f-K)C'(K)/C(K)$ becomes a significant
fraction of 1; i.e., as soon as $C(f)$ and $C(K)$ are significantly
different.

Stated differently, small changes in the exponent cause much greater
changes in the probability density. A better approach is to re-cast
the series as (A.15b)
$$P=\frac{α}{\sqrt{2πε^2 C^2 (K)τ}}  \exp⁡\left[-\frac{(f-K)^2}{2ε^2 α^2 C^2 (K)τ}⋅(1+⋯)\right]$$

**Now I'm confused**:
Not familiar with singular perturbation, I don't quite get how (A.15a) or (A.15b) are derived. Could any one give some hint pls?